# An algebraic element $a$ in a field extension $K/F$ satisfies $a^{q^m}=a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field with order $q$ and characteristic $p$. Show that if $a$ is an algebraic element over $F$ in the extension $K$, then $a^{q^m}=a$ for some $m$.

I have shown that the order of the field satisfies $q=p^n$ for some $n$ and that for every $x\in F$, $x^q=x$. But I am stuck trying to prove the statement above. By definition there is some $P\in F[x]$ such that $P(a)=0$ but I have no idea how to use this.

Comment: Hint: The field $F(a)$ is also finite, with order $q^m$ for some $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any finite field $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\;,\;\;p\;$  a prime, is the set of all roots of $\;x^{p^n}-x\in\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ in an (the) algebraic closure of the prime field, usually denoted by $\;\overline{\Bbb F_p}\;$.

Thus, if $\;a\in K\;$ is algebraic, then $\;a\in \Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ , for some $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ , and thus it is a root of $\;x^{p^n}-x\;$ , and now fill in details.